# Download m3u8 playlist and merge into one C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, m3u8

**Solution 1:**

I tried this by using create a ffmpeg wrapper, read output from cmd with following command:

```
-i \"{m3u8-url-for-download}\" -y -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \"{destination-filename}\"
```

I can get duration, current state for downloading. Everything seems be ok. However sometimes it crashed and I can't detect why. It isn't ALWAYS, but SOMETIME.

**Solution 2:**

I download m3u8 playlist file and get contents within it. It contains an array *.ts file url that I can easily download by using HttpClient. But I don't know how to combine these *.ts file into one mp4 file that keeps their format.

Are there other solutions for doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate the ts segments. Then convert with `ffmpeg -acodec copy -vcodec copy`